# datastax python driver connection time-out with multiprocessing

Tags: cassandra, multiprocessing

The following example :

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.decoder import *
import multiprocessing

def async_query_process(lock, i, process_num):

    if i < process_num:
        lock.acquire()
        cluster = Cluster(['neptune'])
        session = cluster.connect('mercure')
        session.row_factory = tuple_factory 
        lock.release()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(name='process' + str(i+1),
                                        target=async_query_process,
                                        args=(lock, i+1, 2))
    process.start()

lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
process = multiprocessing.Process(name='process' + str(0), target=async_query_process,# cluster_ip_list = self.cluster_ip_list, keyspace=self.keyspace,
                                  args=(lock, 0, 2))
process.start()
```

gives the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test_api.py", line 14, in async_query_process
    session = cluster.connect('mercure')
  File "/home/nkou/workProd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 483, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/home/nkou/workProd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1369, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
  File "/home/nkou/workProd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1405, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'neptune': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating new connection, last_host=None',)})
```

It is mentioned in the datastax python driver doc that cluster and session instances should be created after forking, which is why I have to use that kind of nested subprocess structure.

I am kind of stuck here, maybe I will switch back to previous working cassandra-python drivers.

Thanks !

Niko

Comment: Have you tried to telnet into neptune on port 9042? Have you tried replacing neptune with the IP of the server just to see if that works?

Comment: Hi Alex ! Sorry for the delay in my answer : Yes I've tried, it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This will work: (close session before you spin up a new process)

def async_query_process(lock, i, process_num):

```
if i < process_num:
    lock.acquire()
    cluster = Cluster(['neptune'])
    session = cluster.connect('mercure')
    session.row_factory = tuple_factory
    session.cluster.shutdown()    # close session here
    session.shutdown() 
    lock.release()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(name='process' + str(i+1),
                                    target=async_query_process,
                                    args=(lock, i+1, 2))
process.start()
```

Comment: When you shutdown, don't you need to "restart" somewhere later? Not sure what shutdown does and if it requires further actions later.

Comment: `shutdown()`
Closes all sessions and connection associated with this Cluster. To ensure all connections are properly closed, you should always call shutdown() on a Cluster instance when you are done with it.

Once shutdown, a Cluster should not be used for any purpose.

Comment: Closing a session and opening a new session is going to slow things down terribly imho.